# Function that takes list of GenericType does not accept provided arguments

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to implement a function that takes a list of a generic type. But it does not accept the provided arguments.

```
interface TheInterface<T extends string> {
    theRecord: Record<T, unknown>
}

const theFunction = <T extends string>(...arrayOfInterfaceType:TheInterface<T>[]) => {


return (key: keyof typeof arrayOfInterfaceType[number]['theRecord']) => key

}

const values1 = {theRecord:{value1: ""}}

const values2 = {theRecord:{value2: ""}}

const values1TheInterface: TheInterface<keyof typeof values1.theRecord> = values1

const values2TheInterface: TheInterface<keyof typeof values2.theRecord> = values2


//Works perfectly
const functionWithOneInterface = theFunction(values1TheInterface)
//Intelisense works for key
functionWithOneInterface("value1")
//Does not work
const functionWithTwoInterfaces = theFunction(values1TheInterface, values2TheInterface)
//Intellisense only works for value1
functionWithTwoInterfaces("value1", "value2")
```

The code below is simplified but reflects the same behaviour as the actual code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIElzXkgHlWQgA9IQATAZ2WrClAHMA+ZAbwCgBIMTAJQgIA9lEoAuZIJFiiAGmQBXEAGsQwgO4gWnAL6dOIkPWR8IAMWUIwwYSGQBeZERLkIVWvUYhWACgB0gXBQUHAAngDyMDiQsIgQqGEADhDiGNi4cYSoLADaALoAlI5sXAZQEGCKUPa+KhBhkvVhwjCmyRCtyMGhkdGZ+AkduSCKALYARtD5uQDkZtKilLNFJcjNBvqGdiYAbnAANooQ1ACMjhwLQkvi7PtHEKeSAETPultGe4fH1ABMF+wrjIJHdvhBfi83h8dmBkPcfqd0jE8PFJEiBvECM0umAOl14SdTv4gUs2E4CWcDJ9YRTfujYoM0ZhkVkIFiGji8W1acSBNcxGS4WC-gZOAB6MUAdVEKloKVgQjABzC22MsJgVhsdklwD4ERAGQZ8QuZksIGsthAvgpiOZGKQhXFYuRB2A1Hc7uQGhltBgonWDU4GvNWpAOr1BpZg18zwJp2ejolABFhCdkOpYd6oCpVSZgxbtbr0KhvVH4rQnKbNZbrcLbYaUUgFLT6Y2IInnbhXe7jCg7MqvT7kH6oEKHqcg9XC3wS8Iy0hqDG488FLGwb8E0A)

Answer (score 2):

The Heuristics of the compiler prevent you to use multiple different string literals for `T` here. Once `T` is inferred by the first element, all the other elements must have the same `T`.

You probably want something like this:

```
const theFunction = <T extends TheInterface<any>[]>(
  ...arrayOfInterfaceType: [...T]
) => {
  return (...keys: { [K in keyof T]: keyof T[K]["theRecord"] }) => keys;
};
```

Instead of using `T` to store the keys, just let it store the whole array. Also let's use the spread syntax `[...T]` so that the order of the elements is preserved.

The function you are returning seems to be callable as a *rest parameter*. For the type, we map over `T` and extract the key values for each element `T[K]`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIElzXkgHlWQgA9IQATAZ2WrClAHMA+ZAbwChlkxMAlCAgD2USgC5kgkWKIAaZAFcQAaxDCA7iBYBuTgF9OnESHq9MAMWUIwwYSGQBeZERLkIVWhmy5YiCARwIACeLADaALosABTcyAB0iXBQUHDBAPIwOJB+SKjBAA4QkmGJ8agRnACUTmxcPFAQYIpQDtFlKhDB1JLsyGEA0sigyJ3BwjBoEZJjE2iDEWEARHwQ0qKUSxHI+jWObGPUevp6xvZmAG5wADaKENQAjE4c5mtCG73IV7cQD5JLSx2Oz0JkuNzu1AATM8+qt1mJPt87pD-oD9MCzqYwF9wfcAMww17wiQvJEQPGohRkgAsqKBhkxYJ+j282Tw-kkrN8+ACcVmkzAhQgczJj3icPeYk4bGcooep1B2NFkK5OR5nMwbNyvJ4-N4QpFuKh4oEkso0ueyoV52xMGstnsAHVgHx0iAfGr-M9VlYQDY7CBonLVeykFU9Ha-Q6QM7Xe6tTzoksyQ8luGjIrkJH-U6XehUBphAn-LRnD77QHYjxg5ruf45HFlSHtdUIxXc3wC0W60hqEmU0sFMncZC09asVn2zG813i73oWXLFPYgBIGse0MQKlGvHVThAA)